# Cannot use push of undefined in Lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript-controller

Why cannot I use the `push` method of the array in the case?

Below you will be able to see that I am creating an empty array attribute named `items` in `camping.cmp`. I am setting it using the `default="{}"`.

Then I pass the reference to `items` into the `campingItemForm` here `<c:campingItemForm item="{!v.item}" items="{!items}" />`.

Then in the form I have the controller attached to the button. And when I click the button I expect to be able to get the items array in the controller, and so I am expecting the `push` method being available to me.

But instead of the array I am getting `undefined`. What am I doing wrong here?

Here is the error message.

```
This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it.
Action failed: c:campingItemForm$controller$clickCreateItem [Cannot read property 'push' of undefined]
Failing descriptor: {c:campingItemForm$controller$clickCreateItem}
```

Here are the files.

`campingApp.app` :

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds">
    <c:camping />
</aura:application>
```

`camping.cmp` :

```
<aura:component >
    <aura:attribute name="items" type="Camping_Item__c[]" default="[]"/>
    <aura:attribute name="item" type="Camping_Item__c" default="{ 
                        'sobjectType': 'Camping_Item__c',
                        'campingItemName': 'campingItemNameDefault',
                        'Price__c': 0,
                        'Quantity__c': '0',
                        'Packed__c': false }"/>
    <c:campingHeader />
    <c:campingItemForm item="{!v.item}" items="{!items}" />
    <c:campingList />
</aura:component>
```

`campingItemForm.cmp` :

```
<aura:component >
    <aura:attribute name="item" type="Camping_Item__c" required="true"/>
    <aura:attribute name="items" type="Camping_Item__c" required="true"/>
    <form class="slds-form--stacked">          
            <lightning:input aura:id="campingItemForm" label="Name"
                             name="campingItemName"
                             value="{!v.item.Name}"
                             required="true"/> 
            <lightning:input aura:id="campingItemForm" label="Quantity"
                             name="campingItemQuantity"
                             value="{!v.item.Quantity__c}"
                             min="1"
                             placeholder="QQQQQ"/>
            <lightning:input aura:id="campingItemForm" type="number" label="Price"
                             name="campingItemPrice"
                             formatter="currency"
                             step="0.01"
                             value="{!v.item.Price__c}"/>
            <lightning:input aura:id="campingItemForm" type="checkbox" label="Packed"  
                             name="cmapingItemIsPacked"
                             checked="{!v.newExpense.Reimbursed__c}"/>
            <lightning:button label="Create Camping Item" 
                              class="slds-m-top--medium"
                              variant="brand"
                              onclick="{!c.clickCreateItem}"/>
        </form>
</aura:component>
```

`campingItemFormController.js` :

```
({
    clickCreateItem : function(component, event, helper) {
        var newItem = component.get("v.item");
        var items = component.get("v.items");
        items.push(newItem);
        newItem = new Camping_Item__c();
        component.set("v.item", item);
        component.set("v.items", items);
    }
})
```

Here is what I see after clicking the button:

[image]

Comment: I think it may be because in your `campingItemForm`.cmp `items` is not an array and also, it does not have a default value. Maybe you trying to access the value before setting it hence the undefined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This `items="{!items}"` should be `items="{!v.items}"`.

Whenever you see:

> Cannot read property XXXX of undefined

it means you are trying to access a property (including a function property) from a value that you have failed to set to anything.

Probably not needed to get the code to work, but to keep anyone reading the code same also `name="items" type="Camping_Item__c"` should be `name="items" type="Camping_Item__c[]"`.

Comment: Now I got this error: `This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it.
Action failed: c:campingItemForm$controller$clickCreateItem [Camping_Item__c is not defined]
Failing descriptor: {c:campingItemForm$controller$clickCreateItem}`.

Comment: The error is produced by the line: `newItem = new Camping_Item__c();`.

Comment: What could I try here? Since I am sure that the `Camping_Item__c` exists in my org.

Comment: @oobarbazanoo SObject types are not automatically carried over into the JavaScript. Instead use this `newItem = {sobjectType: "Camping_Item__c"};`.